# sort and rearrange arrays basked on key value pair objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting, filtering

I have 3 or more arrays  that show prices (p) based on weight (w) breakpoints with unique identifiers for every array (i) such as the bellow.

```
var arr1 = [{w:1,p:10,i:"car1"},{w:2,p:15,i:"car1"},{w:3,p:21,i:"car1"}]
var arr2 = [{w:1,p:12,i:"car2"},{w:2,p:13,i:"car2"},{w:3,p:22,i:"car2"}]
var arr3 = [{w:1,p:9,i:"car3"},{w:2,p:12,i:"car3"},{w:3,p:33,i:"car3"}]
```

I want to generate "pricelist" arrays based cheapest, second cheapest, third cheapest etc.. such

```
var cheap1 = [{w:1,p:9,i:"car3"},{w:2,p:12,i:"car3"},{w:3,p:21,i:"car1"}]
var cheap2 = [{w:1,p:10,i:"car1"},{w:2,p:13,i:"car2"},{w:3,p:22,i:"car2"}]
var cheap3 = [{w:1,p:12,i:"car2"},{w:2,p:15,i:"car1"},{w:3,p:33,i:"car3"}]
```

what could be the fastest way to produce such an output.

I tried merging them into one array then sorting them out then looping over the array and pushing the objects into the new arrays based on if the indexes of the objects that had (w) value was equal to the previous (w) value, but it just wouldn't work and i cant seem find a way to solve this.

i tried multiple if then statements in multiple for loops and that worked out but the issue is that i might have some 20 arrays that i want to compare and if statements wont be viable.

appreciate the help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort by `w` property first and then by `p`. For getting a result of the sorted array pushthe object to the array by the remainder of the index.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ w: 1, p: 10, i: "car1" }, { w: 2, p: 15, i: "car1" }, { w: 3, p: 21, i: "car1" }],
    array2 = [{ w: 1, p: 12, i: "car2" }, { w: 2, p: 13, i: "car2" }, { w: 3, p: 22, i: "car2" }],
    array3 = [{ w: 1, p: 9,i: "car3" }, { w: 2, p: 12,i: "car3"  }, { w: 3, p: 33, i: "car3" }],
    [cheap1, cheap2, cheap3] = [...array1, ...array2, ...array3]
        .sort((a, b) => a.w - b.w || a.p - b.p)
        .reduce((r, o, i) => {
            (r[i % 3] ??= []).push(o);
            return r;
        }, []);

console.log(cheap1);
console.log(cheap2);
console.log(cheap3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks so much i totally forgot that reducers exist. not quite how i wanted to structure it  but you pointed me in the right direction